# Cognos Package Deployment

Tags: cognos-10

I am working on Cognos 10.2 and while working on Framework Manager I've successfully created a Data model using MS SQL Server, I deploy the package successfully but when I check the same on IBM Cognos Business Intelligence it does not show me anything inside the Package (No Data Source and No Query Object).
Requesting to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You likely didn't include anything within the Package in Framework Manager.

Right click on package, choose "Edit Definition". You will see all of the layers of the model; ensure that the final (presentation) layer has a green check next to it and not a red X.